# How to display a default 403 page from ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I should be able to display the default 403 Access Denied page from IIS.

So within my VB.Net code I've tried this:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 403
HttpContext.Current.Response.Status = "403 Access Denied"
HttpContext.Current.Response.End()
```

But when this is called I just get:

> This page Can't be displayed

I thought I would be able to display the default/inbuilt 403 page, or am I way off with this?

Answer (score 1):

That code works for me.  Here are some things you can try:

1. Ensure IIS is configured to display the 403 page in the Error Pages section.

[image: IIS Error Pages Section]

2. Use the Custom Errors section in your Web.config

[image: Custom Errors in Web.config]

Comment: Thanks for the info.  So I've check that IIS is configured to show Error Pages (my section looks the same as yours). With the customerrors section, would require me to write my own html page (I was hoping to avoid that as the standard one would be fine)?